# Localizations list on info.plist is incomplete

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, info.plist

I'm trying to add a few languages to the App Store's language list, currently it says my app only supports English, but in fact it supports English, Chinese (Simplified), Spanish and Brazilian Portuguese. I translated my app manually, everything is in code.

I'm trying to overcome this by editing info.plist, I added a `localizations` key, but when I try to add values, there's a small list with just 9 values, as the following image shows:

[image: localizations list with only 9 available values]

How do I get more values? Can I just write any value there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html) might help you. In this link there is a note "If the language doesn’t appear in the Localizations section in the Info pane of your project, add the language before following these steps, as described in [Using Base Internationalization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW2)" Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can just edit the info.plist file with your favourite text editor:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>es</string>
    <string>pt</string>
</array>
```